# Unable to click two continue SPAN buttons with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to click two buttons with the following HTML Code

1.

```
 <span translate="Resources.AddOns.TravelInsurance.Button_ContinueBooking" class="ng-scope">Continue Booking</span>
 The Xpath = //*[@id="cont_to_ins"]/span
```

2. `<button wn-validation-dom="prepaidcards-details" class="orange-btn btn btn-sm bold ng-scope" ng-if="!areOtherAddOnsAfterPrepaidCardsIndexAvailableInAccordion()" id="cont_to_ins" ng-click="continueBooking()"><span translate="Resources.AddOns.PrepaidCards.Button_ContinueBooking" class="ng-scope">Continue Booking</span> <i class="material-icons "></i></button>`

The Xpath =

```
//*[@id="cont_to_ins"]
```

I have tried several codes but getting error that the button cannot be clicked .

Please kindly assist with the code to Find this element and click to move to next page

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Continue Booking')])[1]/following::button[1]")).click();
   log.debug("Click Continue ");




WebElement elementa=  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Continue Booking']/"));   
    JavascriptExecutor executore = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executore.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementa);
```

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable
>   to locate an element with the xpath expression //span[contains(text(),
>   'Continue Booking')])[1]/following::button[1] because of the following
>   error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The
>   string '//span[contains(text(), 'Continue
>   Booking')])[1]/following::button[1]' is not a valid XPath expression. 
>   (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.157)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=74.0.3729.6
>   (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows
>   NT 10.0.17763 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any
>   stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit:
>   https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'WN-HQ-LT-DEV-42', ip: '10.10.11.250', os.name:
>   'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_211' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false,
>   applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false,
>   browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 74.0.3729.6
>   (255758eccf3d24..., userDataDir: C:\Users\ADEYIN~1.ALA\AppDa...},
>   cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions:
>   {debuggerAddress: localhost:64341}, handlesAlerts: true,
>   hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true,
>   locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false,
>   nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy:
>   normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), rotatable:
>   false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false,
>   takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit:
>   0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore,
>   unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 74.0.3729.157,
>   webStorageEnabled: true} Session ID: aebe53b2f0ce483db0acf2034848ecd9
>   *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//span[contains(text(), 'Continue Booking')])[1]/following::button[1]}

Comment: Please take a few minutes to properly format your question. Code should be formatted as code, the error message can be formatted as code or a quote. If you need help with formatting, see the formatting help when you enter the editor. Thanks.

Comment: Also, we need the relevant HTML if you want help building a new locator.

Comment: Read the exception, and you'll know why it doesn't work, it's written right there!

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebdriverWait` to handle dynamic element and following `Xpath`.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath('//button[@id="cont_to_ins"]/span[contains(.,"Continue Booking")]')));
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not written proper XPath

driver.findElement(By.xpath("**(//span[contains(text(), 'Continue Booking')])[1]/following::button[1]"))**.click();
   log.debug("Click Continue ");